# Chow ring of two varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given two smooth projective varieties $X$ and $Y$. Maybe this is elementary but what is the Chow ring $CH(X\times Y)$ in terms of $CH(X)$ and $CH(Y)$?

Comment: This is very far from being elementary!:) No general answer is possible.

Comment: About this, see Ex. IV.4.10 in Hartshorne.

Comment: This is true for varieties having an 'algebraic cellular decomposition'. See Example 19.1.11 in Fulton, Intersection Theory, p. 378.

Comment: @Damian, a little more general result is proved in Totaro's paper "Chow groups, Chow cohomology and linear varieties". The assumption there is that X decomposes into pieces isomorphic to $A^a\times G_m^b$ for some integers $a,b$.

Answer (score 5):

Partial result: For $X,Y/k$ smooth, proper and connected over $k = \bar{k}$, $\mathrm{Pic}(X \times_k Y) = \mathrm{Pic}(X) \oplus \mathrm{Pic}(Y) \oplus \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Alb}_X, \mathrm{Pic}_Y)$. I remember having proved this using motivic cohomology $\mathrm{Pic}(X \times_k Y) = H^{2,1}(X \times_k Y,\mathbf{Z}) = \mathrm{Hom}_{DM^{eff,-}_{Nis}}(M(X \times_k Y), \mathbf{Z}(1)[2])$, the Künneth formula $M(X \times_k Y) = M(X) \otimes M(Y)$ and the splitting $M(X) = \mathbf{Z}(0)[0] \oplus h^1(X) \oplus h^{\geq 2}(X)$.

Perhaps this generalises using $CH^i(X) = H^{2i,i}(X,\mathbf{Z})$ and the splitting of the motive $M(X)$ into Künneth components.

Comment: This may works. For $X$ and $Y$ projective homogenous varieties one has $CH^*(X\times Y)=CH^*(X)\otimes CH^*(Y)$ as graded rings.

Comment: Motivic cohomology is *huge* overkill for the Pic statement.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but it makes it obvious.

Comment: @Aleksa: "This may works ..." That is already false for $\text{CH}^1(X\times Y)$, as Timo's answer explains.