# Chow group of a product

Tags: algebraic-curves, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth varieties over $k$. I was wondering if there is a decomposition of the Chow group $CH(X\times Y)$ in terms of $CH(X)$ and $CH(Y)$ similar to the Kunneth decomposition of $H(X\times Y)$. I'm particularly interested in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are powers of a smooth projective curve. Feel free to impose conditions on $k$.

Comment: Does http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159959/chow-ring-of-two-varieties/159960#159960 help you?

Comment: yes, thanks. I will look at those examples in Hartshorne and Fulton. Is $A$ in the comment of Victor Petrov the additive group? I also don't know what algebraic cellular decomposition means. Have to look that up.

Comment: Also, can one say anything more when $X$ and $Y$ are powers of a curve?

Comment: This is already false with $X,Y$ curves : $\mathrm{Pic}(X\times Y)$ is isomorphic to  $\mathrm{Pic}(X)\oplus \mathrm{Pic}(Y)\oplus \mathrm{Hom}(JX,JY)$, where $JX$ and $JY$ are the Jacobians of $X$ and $Y$.